# How to prove that this is a rational function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have encountered a question like this:

Suppose a complex function $f$ is analytic in $|z|<1$, continuous in $|z| \leq 1$, and $|f|=1$ on $|z|=1$. Show that $f$ can be extended as a rational function.

According to the isolation property of zero points, $f$ has only finite zero points in $|z| \leq 1$. But I don’t know how to show that it’s a rational function. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are finitely many zeros of $f$ in the unit disc. There is a finite
[Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) $p(z)$ having the same zeros as $f$ in the unit disc.
This is designed so that $|p|=1$ on the unit circle. Then $f=pg$
where $g$ is continuous and non-zero on the closed unit disc, holomorphic on the
open unit disc and has $|g|=1$ on the unit circle. By the maximum modulus
principle, $g$ is constant. So $f$ is a constant multiple of a
finite Blaschke product, which is a rational function on $\Bbb C$.